# how to emulate full gc by many StackTraceElement in heap

Tags: java, jvm, java.util.concurrent

Recently My operation colleague report production environment have many full gc, and influence app response time. And he supply an image 
[image]

he especially said StackTraceElement have 85M, and suggests not have these code , e.g.

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Now I want to simulate this situation in my local, and I write a test code like below

```
public class FullGCByLogTest {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FullGCByLogTest.class);
    public static final byte[] _1M = new byte[1 * 1024 * 1024]; //placeholder purpose

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int nThreads = 1000; // concurrent count
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
        while (true) {
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(nThreads);
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
                pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        latch.countDown();
                        try {
                            latch.await(); // waiting for execute below code concurrently
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        }
                        try {
                            int i = 1 / 0;
                            System.out.println(i);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100); // interval 1s every concurrent calling
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
       }

    }
}
```

and I run this class with these vm args

```
-Xmx4m -Xms4m -XX:NewSize=1m -XX:MaxNewSize=1m -XX:+PrintGCDetails
```

then in jvisualvm VisualGC I found old gen is 7 M, but I set max heap is 4m.

[image]

in addition in heapdump I did not find StackTraceElement. So how could I emulate this problem successfully?

[image]

Comment: In order to reproduce it is important to disable preallocated exceptions `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

Comment: Thanks! But add this vm arg, still not find stacktraceelement

Comment: Each `StackTraceElement` contains references to at least two `String` instances (three, if the source file name is known), which in turn refer to a `char[]` array with the actual string contents, which usually outweighs the former objects regarding size. So it’s really strange to see `StackTraceElement` on rank 3 in a statistic, especially when rank 2 is neither `String` nor `char[]`. Do you have deep recursion in your application?

Comment: @Holger Thanks! but you said: "the side effect of the profiler application recording call stacks using StackTraceElements within the JVM itself. That would be in line with that even higher number of HashMap$Entry instances, if we assume that the profiler stores callers in a HashMap". Actually I do not understand, could you give me some link could explain this?

Comment: There are no websites following me and explaining my comments. I just stated one possibility, as we simply don’t know anything about what methodology your colleague used to get this statistic. After all, your colleague’s report contains even more `HashMap$Entry` instances than `StackTraceElement`, so it’s unclear why you’re not worrying about them (or about whatever is the topmost entry)…

Answer (score 3):

The `StackTraceElement` objects are actually created when an exception object is instantiated, and they will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the exception object is unreachable.

I suspect that the real cause for your (apparent) storage leak is that something in your code is saving lots of exception objects.

Calling `printStackTrace()` does not leak objects.  Your colleague has misdiagnosed the problem.  However calling `printStackTrace()` all over the place is ugly ... and if it happens frequently, that will lead to performance issues.

---

Your simulation and the results are a red herring, but the probable reason that the heap is bigger than you asked for is that the JVM has "rounded up" to a larger heap size.  (4Mb is a miniscule heap size, and impractical for most Java programs.)

---

> So how could I emulate this problem successfully?

Emulation is highly unlikely to tell you anything useful.  You need to get hold of a heap dump from the production system and analyze that.

Comment: Thanks! BTW my above code to mock concurrent calling is right? Does have any more precise manner to mock concurrently calling

Comment: There is no "precise" way to "mock" the behavior of concurrency.  It is *non-deterministic*.  But a thread-pool with 1000 threads is pretty pointless.  (And a real application which creates thousands of threads is in serious need of a redesign.  It could be consuming gigabytes of non-heap memory just on the thread stacks.)

Comment: So you think my above way using java code compare with `ab -n10000 -c100 http://foo.com`, which one is more suitable in my case , and which one   is more like  concurrency  in real situation.

Comment: No I don't.  And besides, you have not presented any evidence from which one can conclude that the real problem (too many full GCs) is a concurrency related problem.  I think you are wasting your time with this "theory" of yours.  You would be better off doing what I said above - get hold of a heap dump and analyse it for possible storage leaks.

Comment: …or these `StackTraceElement`s are the side effect of the profiler application recording call stacks using `StackTraceElement`s within the JVM itself. That would be in line with that even higher number of `HashMap$Entry` instances, if we assume that the profiler stores callers in a `HashMap`…

Comment: I guess that is possible, but I would have thought that the profiler agent would use a different representation, and that it wouldn't store it in the regular heap.

Comment: Normally…but we also don’t know whether the statistic of the colleague’s report shows a snapshot or an overall creation count. In the latter case, the use of [`Thread.getAllStackTraces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces--) would explain it.

Comment: because it's a web project deployed in tomcat7 and have many user to use, so I think maybe it's caused by concurrency.

Comment: That is not real evidence.  It is pure guesswork.  You >>might<< get lucky and figure out what the problem is by guesswork ... but I doubt it.  I stand by my advice above.